# GZIP on PHP and NGINX

Tags: php, nginx, compression, gzip

I have a nginx server which houses a php script that outputs a large json.  I want to minimize the network bandwidth load and speed up my app using Gzip and passing a gzipped json output from my server to the client browser.

I have found 2 possible solution:
1. At php script level:

```
// Fetch some data
$data = get_data();

// Turn on output buffering with the gzhandler
ob_start('ob_gzhandler');

// Output as normal
echo json_encode($data);
```

2. At nginx server level by making following changes to config file

   #
   gzip on;
   gzip_proxied any;
   gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
   gzip_vary on;
   gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6].(?!.*SV1)";
   #

My questions is if I make the changes at nginx level, do I again need to use gzip at php script level? Are they mutually exclusive strategies or interdependent.  I am a bit confused

Regards

Comment: you do gzip encoding in your webserver. If you use php to build your own server, you can easily enable gzip support by using ob_gzhandler. If you are using an existing webserver, like nginx or apache, you can configure them to do the compression usually using an external module. When you do this, no need to do anything in php.

Comment: This is correct